# User-agent browser detection

Tags: servlets, browser, http-headers

I am trying to detect the browser and version from the httpservletrequest header variable "user-agent"

The string seems to have lot of information like below
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Is there any utility in java to identify the browser and version from this string ?

Comment: Detecting browser from user agents is a rather tedious work (see [useragentstrings.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/)). What are you trying to do with that information?

Comment: This information is not processed - it's used just for logging purpose

Answer (score 0):

http://haraldwalker.github.io/user-agent-utils/javadoc/
This solution worked for me. ( for some reason safari version was not detected )

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sources:

http://www.bitwalker.eu/software/user-agent-utils

or

https://github.com/haraldwalker/user-agent-utils